# Dependency Injection: The type SimpleTraceWriter must derive from ITraceWriter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

Im using Ninject for DI. One of lines gives me strange error:

```
The type SimpleTraceWriter must derive from ITraceWriter.
Parameter name: service

{"The type SimpleTraceWriter must derive from ITraceWriter.\r\nParameter name: service"}
```

The line of code giving the error:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter), new SimpleTraceWriter(WebContainerManager.Get<ILogManager>()));
```

but SimpleTraceWriter  implements ITraceWriter:

SimpleTraceWriter  code:

```
 public class SimpleTraceWriter : ITraceWriter
    {
        private readonly ILog _log;

        public SimpleTraceWriter(ILogManager logManager)
        {
            _log = logManager.GetLog(typeof(SimpleTraceWriter));
        }

        public void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, TraceLevel level, Action<TraceRecord> traceAction)
        {
            var rec = new TraceRecord(request, category, level);
            traceAction(rec); WriteTrace(rec);
        }
```

...

ITraceWriter code:

```
public interface ITraceWriter
{   
    void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, TraceLevel level, Action<TraceRecord> traceAction);
}
```

Comment: are you sure that in your  configuration you are not referencing an `ITraceWriter` from a different namespace?

Comment: Yes, I was doing it quickly I selected wrong namespace `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization` instead of `System.Web.Http.Tracing;` Thanks guys:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another ITraceWriter interface in a System.Web.Http.Tracing namespace. Try to specify namespace in the line, that is causing the error:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(MyNamespace.ITraceWriter), new SimpleTraceWriter(WebContainerManager.Get<ILogManager>()));
```